# Copy constructor and "Cannot call value of non-function type" error

Tags: swift, copy-constructor

I have a base class A and three subclasses:

```
class A {}
class X : A {}
class Y : A {}
class Z : A {}
```

In my code, I have an instance `m` which I would like to create a copy of, **of the same type**.
I can successfully use the following code:

```
        let n = type(of: m).init(m)
... and in class A: 
        required init(m : A) {
           self.param1 = m.param1
```

I try to simplify things by creating a copy constructor in class A:

```
   func copy() {
      return type(of: self).init(self)
   }
```

but this declaration generates the error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'AType'

Two questions: What am I doing wrong? and Is there a simpler way to create a copy constructor involving subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Prototype desing pattern:

```
     public protocol Copying: class {

    init(_ prototype: Self)
}

extension Copying {
    public func copy() -> Self {
        return type(of: self).init(self)
    }
}

public class A: Copying {

    public var value1: Int
    public var value2: Int

    public init(value1: Int, value2: Int) {
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
    }

    public required convenience init(_ a: A) {
        self.init(value1: a.value1, value2: a.value2)
    }
}
```

and you can use it like:

```
let a = A(value1: 700, value2: 37)

let aCopy = a.copy()
```